# How do I parse a value from JSON file in an array (electron/node.js)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

So, I have this JSON file in which there is an array full of sets of values. I am not really sure how I would go about getting the first value from the very first set of values - that would be the 3 from pink. I am doing all of this in Node. This is all I have, not sure if I am on the right path. Might even be a formating error.

My JSON file:

```
{
  "myArray": [
    {
      "pink": 3,
      "long": 2
    }
    {
      "pink": 4,
      "long": 7
    }
  ]
}
```

My *program*:

```
var app = require('electron').remote;
var fs = require('fs');
var txt = fs.readFileSync('testjson.json', 'utf8');
var additional = JSON.parse(txt);
var parsed = additional["myArray"][0]["pink"];
console.log(parsed);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What did you get in log?

Comment: As a note, if you instead use `require('./testjson.json')`, Node.js will automatically parse it to a simple object that you can manipulate. This doesn't work as well if the contents of testjson.json change frequently, but can be handy for non-confidential config data (though you should really be using environment variables for those).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is not formatted correctly. There should be a comma separating your sets.

```
{
  "myArray": [
    {
      "pink": 3,
      "long": 2
    },
    {
      "pink": 4,
      "long": 7
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: That is it. Thank you so much. Now that it can read the file, I have just made a little tweak to the code to read out the value that I desire and it works as expected.